# How to pass only model[0] to a component from the template in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frontend

I want to pass only the model[0] (first data element) to a component from the template. I have a route file as follows:

```
/order.js
export default Route.extend({

  firstIndex: computed('data', {
    get(){
    return Ember.get(this,'data[0]');
    }
  }),

  model(params) {
    return fetch(`/api/salesrowmodel/${params.order_id}`)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(function(data) {
      return {
        data,
      };
    });
  },
});
```

FirstIndex is a computed property to return first index data of the array. Now in the template, I want to pass the first index data to a component:

```
/order.hbs

<div class="Revenue-values">{{order-detail data=firstIndex.revenueHeader}}</div>
```

My sample model data is as follows:

```
[{
"OrderId": "406-5309498-5972326",
"revenueHeader": {
"Principal": 982.14,
"Product Tax": 117.86,
"Total": 1100
}},
{
"OrderId": "506-5234568-5934567",
"revenueHeader": {
"Principal": 382.54,
"Product Tax": 34.46,
"Total": 234
}}]
```

It shows the null or undefined object is being passed to order-details. Please help me with this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the template is not bound to the route but to the controller. So you would need to move your computed property to the controller.

Next `Ember.get(this,'data[0]');` is invalid. you can not use `Ember.get` to access a numeric property, and so an array element. The dependency key `computed('data',` should also probably be `computed('data.[]',`.

However there is a far simpler approach:

```
{{order-detail data=model.firstObject}}
```

because ember adds `firstObject` and `lastObject` to arrays.

Comment: Hi @Lux, Thanks for the answer. Your solution is working but I wanted the solution to be more general where we can pass any data item model[n] and that's why a computed property. Can you try giving a more general solution? It will be a big help.

Comment: you can do `Ember.get(this,'data')[0];`